# I added a module to react and got this error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, json

When reacta boots up the project,

'REACT_APP_ROOT_CONTAINER_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I got an error like this, how can I solve it?

When reacta boots up the project,

'REACT_APP_ROOT_CONTAINER_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I got an error like this, how can I solve it?

I updated the packages in the react environment, node -v 18, I want the project to stand up. Can you help me?
'REACT_APP_ROOT_CONTAINER_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.